# Allow duplicate in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm relatively new to databases, database architecture and MySQL in general, so forgive me if my method isn't optimal. I have created a table called `comments`, for which i want to store the users `id` in to the column `post_id` which works fine as it stands. This table's sole purpose is to store messages posted on any given users profile and some other related information.

However i want to allow duplicate entries so i can read the `comments` table and look for a certain users `id`, then take the column `comments` from the `comments` table and display them on the users profile where the `id` is matched.

I'd do this by doing an `INNER JOIN` on `comments` and `user_info`, specifically the `post_id` from `comments` and `id` from `user_info`.

When posting the information to the database from a users profile, i get the below error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '59' for key 'post_id'
```

user_info

```
'user_info', 'CREATE TABLE `user_info` (\n  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `username` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,\n  `pass` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,\n  `joined` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),\n  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

comments

```
'comments', 'CREATE TABLE `comments` (\n  `post_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `comment` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,\n  `date_posted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\n  UNIQUE KEY `post_id` (`post_id`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

Let me know if i'm missing anything that would potentially help you answer the question.

Comment: So let me get this straight: you want to have many posts, each uniquely identified, but bound to a specific user id?

Comment: Basically, yes. The `post_id` is basically exactly the same as `id` from `user_info`, which is how i'll identify which comments belong to which user. I don't know of any other way to do it.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to change your comment table to have a column `user_id` which point to a user id, and have post_id used for a unique comment id, so that you may find them easily later on?

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop unique index on post_id:

```
ALTER TABLE `comments` DROP INDEX post_id;
```

Then you can create a non-unique index if necessary:

```
ALTER TABLE `comments` ADD INDEX `post_id` (`post_id`);
```

Also your `comments` table lacks primary key. Create an auto increment integer column: comment_id, that would identify the record.

Answer (score 0):

post_id should be an auto increment field as primary key in columns table that uniquely identifies a tuple (row). You should add another column called user_id that stores the id from user_info table. You should then add an index to user_id column in comments table for faster search.

Comment: What would the query look like to add the user_id column? I've basically done this, but the name of the column is post_id, whereas in reality it's actually just the user_id

Answer (score 0):

You need three tables: users, comments, and commentlist.

The users table just holds user details. The comments table just holds comments. Commentlist has 3 columns: an id, which you won't really use, user id, and comment id.

You can then have multiple user id entries in the commentlist table, all relating to an individual comment id.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your query once again. Because the problem may exits on your select query. You have to remove unique index from post_id column of comments table.

Comment: I haven't yet done the INNER JOIN, since i want to first properly post the information to the database which is erroring at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If a row in `comment` is to be related to a row in `user_info`, and one `user_info` can have zero, one or more `comment`, and `comment` is related to exactly one `user_info`...

Then you'd store the value of the `id` column (PRIMARY KEY) column from the `user_info`, as a value in the `comment` table.

With the InnoDB engine, you can also define a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `comment` ADD 
  `user_info_id` INT COMMENT 'FK ref user_info.id' ;

ALTER TABLE `comment` ADD
  CONSTRAINT `FK_comment_user_info` FOREIGN KEY (`user_info_id`)
  REFERENCES `user_info` (`id`)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Leave current the `post_id` column as a unique key (or change it to a PRIMARY KEY) on the table.

Note that a JOIN operation will return multiple rows, when there are multiple comments for a given user_info

```
  FROM `user_info` u
  LEFT
  JOIN FROM `comment` c
    ON c.user_info_id = u.id
 WHERE u.id = 42
```

If a `comment` can be related to more than one `user_info`, then that would be a many-to-many relationship, and the normative pattern to implement that would be to add a third association table, a row in the association table would have foreign key references to both the `user_info` table and the `comment` table.